# PHP memory limit issue editing multiple files

Tags: php, image, memory, limit

I have a script that loops through a directory and edits all the images within it to certain sizes, the problem being that there are 1,000 images totaling up to 300MB.

Is there a way to remove this created image from the memory after each loop so that it doesn't count towards php memory_limit or do I just need to set a memory limit of -1?

```
foreach($image as $file){
    // obviousment this provides a valid image resource
    $new_image = Common::resizeImg($file['tmp_name'], $file['ext'], 215, 121);
    imagejpeg($new_image, SERVER_ROOT."/img/media/small-".$id.$file_ext, 100);

    // clear/reset this memory???
}
```

Comment: I hope you execute that from console? :) If so - try to split it up in smaller tasks. But of course you can set the `memory_limit` to -1. But that can be dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try invoking [`imagedestroy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php), which will clean up any memory associated with the passed-in image resource:

```
foreach($image as $file){
    // obviousment this provides a valid image resource
    $new_image = Common::resizeImg($file['tmp_name'], $file['ext'], 215, 121);
    imagejpeg($new_image, SERVER_ROOT."/img/media/small-".$id.$file_ext, 100);

    imagedestroy($new_image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you [imagedestroy](http://php.net/imagedestroy) after you've written to the disk - otherwise you're adding each new image into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the **memory_limit** in php.ini to anything above the 16MB by default.

In my case i put it in 64 or 128 which is enough. Also you could free the memory with imagedestroy. For example:

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
imagedestroy($image);

This way it frees the used memory.

Comment: You're right, but this script is being passed between a number of different shared hosting providers, so I was looking for a simpler solution.